# select max value within grouped ids

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the values

```
ID  RefID value
1    1       0
2    1       200
3    2       300
4    3       100
5    3        0
```

I need the result like below

```
ID  RefID value
1    1       200
2    1       200
3    2       300
4    3       100
5    3       100
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You want zeros to be the highest value? What if there is a row 6, 1, 100 for example. For RefID =1, do you want 100 or 200? Average of non-zero values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you want the max value of `value` for each RefID:-

```
select m.ID, m.RefID, g.value
from myTable m inner join
(
 select max(value) as value, RefID from myTable group by RefID
) g
on m.RefID = g.RefID
```

Comment: Added RefID to derived aggregate. Otherwise +1